# ¿Cómo mostrar una archivo JSON recibido desde php en una tabla en html?

Tags: ajax

Este es el array que recibo de php, quiero mostrar la identificacion, el tipoidentificacion, nombres, etc. En una tabla html

{"identificacion":"34","tipoidentificacion":"CC","nombres":"Que ","apellidos":"Haces","estrato":"3","telefonos":"12345","fecha":"2022-11-21","hora":"10:20:00"}

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de la respuesta satisfactoria del ajax, podrias crear con javascript los elementos de tu tabla, suponiendo que tienes la estructura de una tabla así:

```
<table id="table_report">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">identificacion</th>
                <th scope="col">tipoidentificacion</th>
                <th scope="col">nombres</th>
                <th scope="col">apellidos</th>
                <th scope="col">estrato</th>
                <th scope="col">telefonos</th>
                <th scope="col">fecha</th>
                <th scope="col">hora</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="body_report">

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Debes agregar un identificador a la etiqueta `<body>`, y en tu ajax deberas crear elemento por elemento y añadirlo a tu tabla de esta forma:

```
var $tablebody = document.getElementById("body_report");//Obtienes el body de tu tabla
result= {"identificacion":"34","tipoidentificacion":"CC","nombres":"Que ","apellidos":"Haces","estrato":"3","telefonos":"12345","fecha":"2022-11-21","hora":"10:20:00"};
```

```js
var $tablebody = document.getElementById("body_report");//Obtienes el body de tu tabla
    result= [{"identificacion":"34","tipoidentificacion":"CC","nombres":"Que ","apellidos":"Haces","estrato":"3","telefonos":"12345","fecha":"2022-11-21","hora":"10:20:00"}];

                    for (var a = 0; a < result.length; a++) {
                        let $tr = document.createElement('tr');
                        let $td_identificacion = document.createElement('td');
                        $td_identificacion.textContent = result[a].identificacion;
                        $tr.appendChild($td_identificacion);
                        let $td_tipoidentificacion = document.createElement('td');
                        $td_tipoidentificacion.textContent = result[a].tipoidentificacion;
                        $tr.appendChild($td_tipoidentificacion);
                        let $td_nombres = document.createElement('td');
                        $td_nombres.textContent = result[a].nombres;
                        $tr.appendChild($td_nombres);
                        let $td_apellidos = document.createElement('td');
                        $td_apellidos.textContent = result[a].apellidos;
                        $tr.appendChild($td_apellidos);
                        let $td_estrato = document.createElement('td');
                        $td_estrato.textContent = result[a].estrato;
                        $tr.appendChild($td_estrato);
                        let $td_telefonos = document.createElement('td');
                        $td_telefonos.textContent = result[a].telefonos
                        $tr.appendChild($td_telefonos);
                        let $td_fecha = document.createElement('td');
                        $td_fecha.textContent = result[a].fecha;
                        $tr.appendChild($td_fecha);
                        let $td_hora = document.createElement('td');
                        $td_hora.textContent = result[a].hora;
                        $tr.appendChild($td_hora);
    
                        $tablebody.appendChild($tr);
                    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="table_report" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">identificacion</th>
                    <th scope="col">tipoidentificacion</th>
                    <th scope="col">nombres</th>
                    <th scope="col">apellidos</th>
                    <th scope="col">estrato</th>
                    <th scope="col">telefonos</th>
                    <th scope="col">fecha</th>
                    <th scope="col">hora</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="body_report">
    
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

```
                for (var a = 0; a < result.length; a++) {
                    let $tr = document.createElement('tr');
                    let $td_identificacion = document.createElement('td');
                    $td_identificacion.textContent = result[a].identificacion;
                    $tr.appendChild($td_identificacion);
                    let $td_tipoidentificacion = document.createElement('td');
                    $td_tipoidentificacion.textContent = result[a].tipoidentificacion;
                    $tr.appendChild($td_tipoidentificacion);
                    let $td_nombres = document.createElement('td');
                    $td_nombres.textContent = result[a].nombres;
                    $tr.appendChild($td_nombres);
                    let $td_apellidos = document.createElement('td');
                    $td_apellidos.textContent = result[a].apellidos;
                    $tr.appendChild($td_apellidos);
                    let $td_estrato = document.createElement('td');
                    $td_estrato.textContent = result[a].estrato;
                    $tr.appendChild($td_estrato);
                    let $td_telefonos = document.createElement('td');
                    $td_telefonos.textContent = result[a].telefonos
                    $tr.appendChild($td_telefonos);
                    let $td_fecha = document.createElement('td');
                    $td_fecha.textContent = result[a].fecha;
                    $tr.appendChild($td_fecha);
                    let $td_hora = document.createElement('td');
                    $td_hora.textContent = result[a].hora;
                    $tr.appendChild($td_hora);

                    $tablebody.appendChild($tr);
                }
```

La instrucción `document.createElement`de JavaScript, te permite crear elementos HTML, la instrucción `appendChild` te permite añadir como hijo un elemento a otro.

Comment: Gracias, si me funcionó

Comment: @EliasibBenitez puedes votar la respuesta si resolvió tu problema.